# How on{X} works?

Tags: javascript, android, onx

I recently got to know about on{X}, which allows user to define rules and trigger actions based on the rule. 
How this works exactly? How on{X} makes device calls? Does it have a base application running on Android phone and then programming on top of it?

Comment: On{X} is not working for my HTC Sensation, unable to login in facebook

Comment: didnt go well with my sony xperia sola as well...

Comment: https://www.onx.ms/#!landingPage

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell. on{x} is a framework for developing small JavaScripts that can do advanced functions on your phone. For instance. I have a script that during my meetings the phone will automatically go to vibrate then go back to a normal ringer when the meeting is over (or supposed to be over).

Comment: Thanks for your response Mike.
How it calls device APIs?
Does it have a framework on which these custom javascript works on? I wanted to develop something similar to that and was wondering how can I achieve same functionality. What I thought of creating a layer on which I can interpret the commands from the script and then handle it on device level,is that correct approach?

Comment: Well... look through their API documentation. I don't know anything more than what is in there and few scripts I have modified.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an application that needs to be running on the device at all times that you wish the scripts to work. Basically the app just feeds on all of the trigger data occurring on the phone and relays that information back to the scripts you have installed. If one matches the trigger in an event that function is then executed. As for the more tricky questions like 'how does it interpret this' and 'how does the layer interact on this level' I do not know, however this is purely trigger based. You cannot run a function independently, there is no input and in terms of launching apps, there is very little in the api to really make this a worthwhile platform (so far)